# MySql missing packages on setup

Tags: mysql, installation

I'm currently trying to setup a mysql server on my linux platform (centos). I've been following a simple Youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZvf_k99C0Q). The jist of the tutorial demonstrates how to download mySql through the following steps:

1.- Grab download link mysql via this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=489467
. The direct download can be taken from here: https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm

2.- Enter terminal & run `wget {download link}`

3.- run command `rpm -qplp {filename}`

4.- run command `sudo rpm -ivh https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-1.noarch.rpm`

5.- run command `sudo yum install -y mysql-server`

However, when I run the final command I get a bunch of "missing package" notifications. I have very little centos experience, so I'm not sure how to address this problem. The output after I run the final command is:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.28)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-8.0.21-1.el8.x86_64 (mysql80-community)
       Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit)
```

As you can see, there are missing packages. I looked up online when the situation might happen, but it refers me to the mysql documentation in which I cannot find a solution for.

Does anybody know whats going on? How to I address these missing packages?

Comment: You should ask this type of question on https://superuser.com/ because it's not code-related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install *mysql* by `rpm` after downloading it or install it directly via `yum`. Not both of them, which results inconsistency in dependencies.

It is highly recommended to install mysql by yum. Yum is a package manager. It automatically resolves dependencies and install them simultaneously (any package will be installed with its dependencies). RPM doesn't resolve dependencies, you must install them manually.

You first need to install a repository by rpm and then try to install mysql from that repository. So you need to run `yum update` after installing any repository.

Try this in a fresh OS.

```
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
yum update

sudo yum install mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysqld
```